# ASP.NET MVC Redirect to file://

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have string data in the form

http://site.com/location

file://server/folder/

I am showing the data as links so clicking on the link takes you to the appropriate web site or file location. Clicking on a link built from 'http://...' data works fine but I get an 'unable to display web page' message when I click on a link built from 'file://' data.

I'm building the link using Html.ActionLink, passing the data as a parameter to a HandleLink method on the controller. The HandleLink method just does Redirect(data). I know the data is coming in correctly because I can copy the incoming value in the debugger and paste in in the address bar of my browser and that works as expected.

How can I make the 'file://' links work correctly?

**EDIT:** I botched the first question I asked here -- I hope they have a badge for that. The 'file://...' data items are to a folder, not a specific file. Does that make any difference?

Comment: You can't access files local to the web server on the remote browser with a file url.

Comment: Are you saying that you want the entire contents of the folder downloaed or do you want the user to be able to see the contents then pick the file they want to download?

Comment: What I really want to have happen is what happens when you do this manually in IE -- a Windows Explorer window opens to the folder specified in the hyperlink.

Comment: I think what you want is to allow directory browsing in IIS

Comment: This works just fine if I do it manually -- I can take the string that's being passed to the Redirict method straight out of the debugger and paste it into an IE address bar and the network folder opens. I was about to state that it seems like an MVC routing issue when the answer dawned on me -- don't send the link through a controller using Html.ActionLink, just hand code the anchor tag. All is now well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can't use file:\ to get files on a remote server however you can serve the files using something like the following:

```
 public FileContentResult GetFile(int fileID)
 {
   string fileName = GetFileNameFromID(fileID);  //Retruns path and filename on server
   string contentType = "text/csv";  //or other appropriate type 

   return new FilePathResult(fileName, contentType); 
 }
```

Much more info [here](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/8/uploading_and_returning_files)

Comment: Thank you -- this answers the question I asked, but perhaps not the question I meant to ask as per my edit in the original question. I appreciate the response.